Alert! Scammed by a fake ethereum sniping bot from a YouTube video
I've been scammed 2000$ following this youtube video  (probably will be removed soon), from the youtube channel @James_Watkin that guide you to implement a Ethereum sniping "bot" to generate ETH, but it ends up transfering all the money to this account: 0x402a0BE1e3d80Bff0F16C1B07c85b15318565ec5
The code was available here. Basically, the bot doesn't do any sniping, just build the previous account address in a complex way, so you don't see it at first glance, and when you press withdraw, you will lose all the money that you previously transer.
I already reported to Youtube, but after 12 hrs the video is still available.
You can see a lot of people were scammed with amounts between 0.4 and 2 ETH.
See etherscan.
Is there any kind of solution?
